# jquery ajax - success function

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax

I had a perfectly well working jquery ajax function but I'm making it better.

I had this:

```
  function MakeAjaxCalls () {
      .....
      $.ajax({
        ...
        success: function (msg) {
        var data = msg.hasOwnProperty("d") ? msg.d : msg;
        .... 
        },
        error: function (xhr, status, error) {alert(xhr.statusText);}
      });
  }
```

It was working fine. Now I want to do this:

```
   function MakeAjaxCall() {

      $.ajax({
        ...
        success: MySuccessFunction,
        error: MyErrorFunction
      });

    }

    function MySuccessFunction(TheJsonData) {
    alert("baaaam"); // no baaaam
    ....
    }

    function MyErrorFunction(){ 
    ....
    }
```

The problem is that it never gets to MySuccessFunction. However, when I look at the network activity, I still get the correct data up and down the wire. I tried changing the line with both  **success: MySuccessFunction(TheJsonData) and success: MySuccessFunction(TheJsonData.d)** to add a parameter, but it's still not triggering and in every case, I don't get a javascript error either; it just doesn't trigger.

What am I missing?

Comment: you need to post your real code...I cant say what is wrong without that information.

Comment: This works, the error must be elsewhere in your code. Post real code...

Comment: No baaaam today. Baaaam tomorrow. There's always a baaaam tomorrow.

Comment: @frenchie, there is nothing wrong with the code you have posted. I have explicitly written a jsfiddle for you to illustrate you that the code you have shown works perfectly fine: http://jsfiddle.net/uedUg/ So if you have some problem, please show your real code. The one that would allow us to reproduce the problematic behavior.

Comment: nevermind, it was a spelling mistake in the code. Ooops

Comment: @frenchie Not sure why you'd accept an incorrect answer then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the code is organized in that fashion, `MySuccessFunction` is not defined at the time you make the call to `jQuery.ajax({ ... })`.

I would recommend defining the success function -before- your call to `jQuery.ajax`

Comment: Ok, I moved the success function above the function that calls the server; no change.